# Connecting to Crystal Reports 4.6 from VB

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, crystal-reports

How can I connect to a Crystal Reports 4.6 report that connects to SQL Server 2005 as a data source, using Visual Basic?

I don't want to specify the connection string in the report. I want to pass the connection from VB. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago I worked on Crystal 4.5 (I don't remember a 4.6).  The way to change the connection details is still pretty much like it is today - Find the tables collection for each report and set the location & log on information for each one.  Sub reports were a pain though.  You had to go through each section of the report to find out if it contained a subreport, then get its table collection.